# output of p[-2] in C array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I was trying the below code snippet. Please help me in understanding how the o/p is coming as 2? What does `p[-2]` mean here?

```
int main(void){
    int ary[4] = {1, 2, 3, 6};

    int *p = ary + 3; 

    printf("%d\n", p[-2]); 
}
```

Comment: Array indexing is equivalent to [pointer arithmetic](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21341838/1708801)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ary` is an array of four `int`s. This will be put in memory like this:

```
 |  1  |  2  |  3  |  6  |
    ^     ^           ^
    |     |           |
   ary  p - 2         p
```

By saying `p = ary + 3`, you're setting `p` to the address of the fourth element in the array. So, `p` is pointing to `6`. `p[-2]` is equal to `*(p - 2)`. That means you point `p` to the second element in the array, and access its value: `2`.

Comment: you mean simple mathematics...p= arr+3; p-2 => arr+3-2 => arr+1 => arr[1].....Correct me If I am wrong.

Comment: Exactly, you got it right! Please accept an answer if it helped you.

Comment: `ary` is an array of 4 `int`s, instead of a pointer to an array of 4 `int`s.

Comment: Thanks, edited it. Feel free to edit anything if needed.

Answer (score 0):

`int *p = ary + 3` points to ary[3] so if you move the pointer two steps back you will get ary[1]

Comment: @deviantfan Sorry for the incorrect index.